# Allow Kile to show subfiles in the structure tree

Tags: kile

I am using the compiled version of `Kile` since a while (version 2.9.94). As my projects I am working on are large and take a longer time to compile, I am using `subfile{}` to speed up the compilation (which works quite nicely). However, in the `structure` tree of Kile, these files are not displayed and I have to manually open the files into Kile in order to edit them. Is there any possible way to get the files which are included via the `subfile` keyword are shown up in the `structure` tree as well? I read  something that I can activate the inclusion of such files in `Kile -> Settings -> Build` somewhere but I could not find anything there.

Note: When I change the `subfile` to `include` it directly gets visible in the `structure` tree of Kile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that, due to the fact that `subfile` mimics separate latex documents itself, that Kile cannot recognize them. However, I found an easy workaround by simply creating a `Project` in Kile and add all the files manually. That's good enough and resolves my issue.